# How to chose between 9V or 12V (or others) DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc, power-electronics, power-consumption

I see a lot of devices working either with a 9V DC input or a 12V DC input, usually provided through a DC jack connector. I was wondering about advantages and/or inconvenients of both voltages.

Indeed, most of the time, this input voltage goes almost directly through a regulator providing 5V or 3V3 to the rest of the circuit, supplying current for MCU and other components.

Then, why a standard has not been adopted to fix the input voltage to one of those two voltages and also, why is it 9V and 12V in 90% of the cases ? (I have never seen a PSU delivering 10V, 8V or others).

I do think there is something to do with efficiency and dissipated power in power supplies and/or regulators but I can't really answer the questions above.

Answer (score 4):

So, first of all, you get a power supply that fits your need. If you, for example, have an amplifier that will give you more output power if supplied with higher supply voltage, well, pick the highest supply voltage.

> I do think there is something to do with efficiency and dissipated power in power supplies and/or regulators but I can't really answer the questions above.

More about availability and cost:

Since these voltages used to be so common, power supplies are really cheap for these, because they are manufactured in millions.

Because the power supplies are so cheap, these voltages became so common.

So, if your device can take in anything between 8 and 10 V, you'd probably pick 9 V, simply because you don't have to look far to find a supply.

12 V might partially be popular because back-back-back in the day, that'd be a typical lead-acid battery voltage, so quite a bit of circuitry was based around that.

Comment: And if you have an input range of 9V to 12V and the first part of the circuit is a regulator you would optimally pick 9V to reduce your losses.

Comment: 12V is still a typical lead-acid battery voltage; most non-electric vehicles have a 12V battery.

Comment: I understand that now that those power supplies are so popular and cheap, we are somehow "forced" to chose one of those. However, I was also interested in chosing 9V vs 12V for applications that do not require that much power. As I said, a lot of consumer electronics products are using a regulator to only power a MCU and a couple of ICs with 3V3, offering often 500mA or more where less than 100mA is needed. Is there a better choice ? Would you first choose your regulator and then your power supply voltage to get the best out of it or the opposite, chosing the power supply voltage first ?

Comment: @jusaca, are there 3V3 regulator (example) that are somehow more power efficient under 12V than 9V or what you said is always true? For example if I need 3V3 with high current, would I pick 12V instead of 9V ?

Comment: @J.K. Well, you could always use USB, which is a 5V supply.

Comment: Well, if you have really high powers and long supply leads you might want to use a higher voltage (in this case 12V) to reduce the loss in your cables. But from a regulator perspective I can not think of a case where 12V would be more effienct than 9V if you want to go to 3.3V.

Comment: @jusaca "if you just regulate down, you'd go for the lower" isn't generally true! If you, for example, need 6 V, but that with a high dynamic of load, then it's easier to build and especially easier to build effectively to use the larger margin from the 12 V supply.